# Move existing outer document to inner document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-update

Given a collection of documents similar to the following document

```
{
"description": "janeetjack",
"name": "Pocog bistro janeetjack"
}
```

where name is a unique field

How do  I  update all existing documents and add additional fields so it looks like this

```
{
"userDetails":{
"description": "janeetjack",
"name": "Pocog bistro janeetjack"
},
"userLikes":{
"likes": "food",
"plays": "ball"
},

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `set` and `unset` on all docs with `updateMany`

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CbVBFU2ag9C)

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$set": {
    "userDetails.description": "$description",
    "userDetails.name": "$name",
    "userLikes.like": "abs"
  },
  "$unset": {
    description: 1,
    name: 1
  }
})
```